# Swap columns in dataframe in Pandas doesn't work

Tags: python, pandas

```
        def columnchange (df_old, a=None, b=None):
             x=df_old[a]
             df_old[a]=df_old[b]
             df_old[b]=x
             return df_old
```

I am wondering why this column swapping is not working. It makes both the columns of the df_old equal. An explanation for this would be helpful. I am able to swap the columns using column index though. But don't know why this is not working.

Comment: Why're you not swapping jsut the column names instead?

Comment: I just tried this approach first, which works fine in case say swapping two integer values. But I would like to know the reason why this is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Alternative I** - as per [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html)

```
df.loc[:, ['b', 'a']] = df[['a', 'b']].to_numpy()
```

**Alternative II**

The reason is that you don't create copies, you create references.

try this:

```
    def columnchange (df_old, a=None, b=None):
         x=df_old[a].copy()
         df_old[a]=df_old[b].copy()
         df_old[b]=x
         return df_old
```

Further explaination:

```
x = df_old[a]
```

means you could do `x = x + 1` and the result will be in `df_old[a]` as well. Because you created a reference, or lets say a "synonym" of the series, not a copy.

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html

Comment: @franjefriten, thanks! Added it to the answer.  :)